# Can a plain sheet of stainless steel adhering to the 316 grade be regarded as food safe at every finish level?

Tags: metal, food-chemistry, metallurgy, iron

My question is not purely about chemistry but it definitely involves it.

I was looking for a while to buy a food-grade stainless steel plate that would fit my home pizza gas oven (to have the dough placed on), and from my research the best possible solution was to find someone who can specially cut 316 stainless steel to the befitting proportions.

I only found one place that agreed to consider such a small order, and it should be done by tomorrow. But now I'm not certain I can automatically count on its food-safety just because the steel is 316 grade. I read at least regarding regular carbon steel sheets they are often hot rolled, which leaves "mill scale" that might chip off, and that they also may be treated with acids that might still be present if the finish level is crude.

I wasn't told the specific finish type for the sheet used, but they said "it's fairly smooth, not mirror-polished". Can that be a food-safety concern even when 316 stainless steel is the material? Is it advised I'll process it in some way to reduce the chance of hazardous chemicals leaching into the food?

**EDIT: Here are photos of the plate I got:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Personally I would wire-brush the whole shebang and then wash like a normal dish. That should bring it down to a "true" 316 surface and remove whatever industrial residues that possibly remain.

Comment: @AngerDensity As I already had pizza dough made in advance and the people there claimed as it's 316 it should be safe already, I washed it with soap and dish scrubber, heated it up in the oven for 20 or so minutes and later washed it again. I'd rather have it polished first but let's hope it's indeed fine as is.

Comment: @AngerDensity I will update that while the sheet didn't seem to become warped during warm up, when I placed the pizza dough parts of the sides went up 1 to 2 centimeters. I suppose this is because the upper surface became colder due to the dough absorbing heat and that made it contract towards to middle? Anyway, it seems to correct itself after removing to pizza and letting the temperatures even up, but I wonder if that repeating warping–unwarping could result in the metal breaking at some point?

Answer (score 2):

There are no special "food grades" although advertisements often claim it. There are grades most commonly used for food equipment; food equipment is primarily 316 and 304. The 316 has some advantage for corrosive foods. A home oven would be such mild service that either grade would be fine. That is, if food has been processed it has very , very likely been contacted by 316 and/or 304 so they are "food safe". Stainless sheet is cleaned ; there are about 4 common commercial finishes according to a net search. Some combination of pickling, heat-treatment, and rolling, and possible sanding. I expect washing with soap and water will produce a safe surface after any of these processes.  I can't imagine you would encounter scale as may be on thick plate.

Comment: Well, the gas oven is rather high temperature, it can reach about 500 Celsius near the burners, but to my understanding the 316 should still withstand this. The sheet will be 2mm thick (I actually planned on 3mm originally but the price became close to what I paid for the pizza oven, which seemed excessive) if that gives any indication. But I still read on some sources stainless steel is also often "pickled" with acids to remove surface roughness: is that a concern?

Comment: I picked up the plate today, it looks a bit like it's made of scrap metal (photos are added to the question). While they told me that as it's 316 (regarding which, the most I could verify is that it's non-magnetic, but frankly what I have is their word) it is fine like that and can go into the oven with food, I wonder if all of this surface junk is something that should be cleaned/polished out somehow or not. The sheet manufacturer's logo for example, how do you think it's imprinted?

Comment: Washing with soap and water should be fine; scouring may be needed to remove stencil ink. 316 may be anywhere from non-magnetic to very magnetic depending on the amount of cold work.  Annealed is non-magnetic which is apparently what you have. Specifications such as ASTM generally require metals to be marked with certain information. ; usually an ink jet stencil. US government generally requires marking for country of origin.

Comment: Soap and water removed some of the visible dirt, although not everything. The serial number visible on the piece returns nothing on Google, although there was probably more written which was cut off from this piece. My cousin does some work with metals and said the imprint is usually laser carved? The one thing that is a bit strange is the weight being 1420 grams rather than the expected 1460 grams (calculating cylindrical volumes against about 8,000KG/M² density of stainless 316), but it MIGHT be that the thickness is just 1.9 and a bit, it's hard to tell with a mechanical caliper.