# Can a thin stainless steel plate warping and unwarping in a gas oven due to temperature gradients break at some point?

Tags: metal, thermal-conductivity

[This is in continuation of a previous question:](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/163940/can-a-plain-sheet-of-stainless-steel-adhering-to-the-316-grade-be-regarded-as-fo)

I have a specially cut 316 stainless steel plate, 345mm diameter * 2mm thicknesses, used in a butane pizza oven that can reach 500 degrees Celsius as a base for the pizza dough.

The plate doesn't seem to warp at all during the warm up period, but when I place dough onto it the plate's sides warp upwards a centimeter or two. I suppose this is because the dough cools the upper side of the plate too quickly and that causes it to contract asymmetrically.

When the pizza is removed the plate seem to flatten out pretty quickly. Will such cyclic deformation pattern damage the integrity of the material in the long run?

Answer (score 3):

No, the temperature differences are relatively small in a home oven. It will distort but not crack. Thermal fatigue can be caused near temperatures like 1600 F over thousands of cycles. Heat-treatment containers are typically nickel alloys which have physical properties very similar to 316 ( austenitic structure). They can be cycled to very high temperatures ( 1800 F) every day for years before possibly cracking.

Comment: I'd say 500 degrees Celsius (932 Fahrenheit) is above what's usually defined as home oven temperatures, but I suppose it's still within safe range according to your answer. The fact that it flattens back to normal tells me the distortion doesn't really affect the molecular structure of the plate. Although I did read something called carbide precipitation can start occurring above 430 Celsius or so, but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: And the warping means that the thermal stresses are being relieved. Certainly flexing from a pizza a day for the rest of the OP's life will have no fatigue impact at all.

Comment: @JonCuster But here the warping is caused by the thermal differentiation when one side of the plate is cooled rapidly by the pizza dough, which seems more stressful than a slower and more symmetrical cooling such as when the plate is left to cool off after the oven is turn off. And I don't make pizza every day, but when I do it's about 4 pizzas one after the other, so there could be 4 warp-unwarp cycles within 20 or so minutes.

Comment: The number of cycles is still so low as not to be an issue. For real fatigue failures you need fairly high stresses, and your plate readily flexes to relieve them.

Comment: @JonCuster To extrapolate on the situation, the effect as is happens with the dough being dropped in using a floured pizza peel. The issue is that the heat transfer is not that great actually and the bottom crust is a bit lacking, so I think of trying to actually oil the peel (and thus the dough's underside). Oil would increase heat transfer, but perhaps that would also cause more serious warping that could prove detrimental? I do think I may lower the oven heat in that situation as the oil may burn too much which would be unhealthy and unsavory.